# I cannot get the inner value of a JSON object

Tags: karate

I cannot get the inner nested key's value of this json object (it gets response from our API call, I just only copy the response from karate)

```
[
  {
    "code": 200,
    "result": "[{\"distinct\":false,\"operatetime\":\"2019-05-17 17:01:01\",\"personid\":\"e8edec61-fd1a-4c69-8b60-fb8d21d06095\",\"sampleid\":\"1c9410cd-608d-4eb1-8d12-c8f2faf7fca4\"}]"
  }
]
```

```
And def tempreponse = [{"code":200,"result":"[{\"distinct\":false,\"operatetime\":\"2019-05-17 17:01:01\",\"personid\":\"e8edec61-fd1a-4c69-8b60-fb8d21d06095\",\"sampleid\":\"1c9410cd-608d-4eb1-8d12-c8f2faf7fca4\"}]"}]
```

And def temp1 = tempreponse[0].result  <- this sentence works 
And def temp1 = tempreponse[0].result[0] <- however, this doesn't work, the print of temp1 is blank

In fact, I need to get the value of personid and sampleid, but failed

Comment: You are putting a **string** into `result`, but you are trying to access it as an array. The string needs to be parsed first.

Comment: `result` is not a nested object, but a simple string value - that itself _contains_ JSON again. You need to JSON-decode `tempreponse[0].result`, before you get an array of objects with properties to access.

Comment: yes, I see. Thanks for your kindly help.  Then the response from our production is incorrect  or the response from karate is something wrong, I will dig into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah your response looks really wrong, a string within a JSON and all. But even if that is the expected response, Karate can handle it. Refer the documentation on type conversions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

```
* def response =
"""
[
  {
    "code": 200,
    "result": "[{\"distinct\":false,\"operatetime\":\"2019-05-17 17:01:01\",\"personid\":\"e8edec61-fd1a-4c69-8b60-fb8d21d06095\",\"sampleid\":\"1c9410cd-608d-4eb1-8d12-c8f2faf7fca4\"}]"
  }
]
"""
* json result = response[0].result
* def personId = result[0].personid
* match personId == 'e8edec61-fd1a-4c69-8b60-fb8d21d06095'
```

Comment: wow~ ⊙o⊙ Yes, it works. Karate is so outstanding, I like it.   Thanks for your quick reply